# pandas: find or mark first occurrence of a new high over a lookback window

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following code which adds a cool to indicate whether the closing value is a new 52 week high.

```
    df1['52wkh'] = df1['high'].rolling(min_periods=1, window=252).max()
    df1['is_52wkch'] = df1['close'] >= df1.shift(1)['52wkh']
```

This produces data that looks like this:

```
                  close         high        52wkh  is_52wkch
date                                                        
2021-11-22  4682.939941  4743.830078  4743.830078      False
2021-12-27  4791.189941  4791.490234  4791.490234       True
2021-12-28  4786.350098  4807.020020  4807.020020      False
2021-12-30  4778.729980  4808.930176  4808.930176      False
2022-01-04  4793.540039  4818.620117  4818.620117      False
2023-06-12  4338.930176  4340.129883  4340.129883       True
2023-06-13  4369.009766  4375.370117  4375.370117       True
2023-06-14  4372.589844  4391.819824  4391.819824      False
2023-06-15  4425.839844  4439.200195  4439.200195       True
2023-06-16  4409.589844  4448.470215  4448.470215      False
```

What i would like to do is actually mark true only the first occurrence of a high within that rolling window.   so the table should look like this actually:

```
                  close         high        52wkh  is_52wkch
date                                                        
2021-11-22  4682.939941  4743.830078  4743.830078      False
2021-12-27  4791.189941  4791.490234  4791.490234       True
2021-12-28  4786.350098  4807.020020  4807.020020      False
2021-12-30  4778.729980  4808.930176  4808.930176      False
2022-01-04  4793.540039  4818.620117  4818.620117      False
2023-06-12  4338.930176  4340.129883  4340.129883       True
2023-06-13  4369.009766  4375.370117  4375.370117      False
2023-06-14  4372.589844  4391.819824  4391.819824      False
2023-06-15  4425.839844  4439.200195  4439.200195      False
2023-06-16  4409.589844  4448.470215  4448.470215      False
```

Im thinking if i can count the number of these occurrences over the 52 week window, then i could filter for a value of 1. Something like below:

`df1.groupby((df1['is_52wkch'] != df1['is_52wkch'].shift(1)).cumsum()).cumcount()+1`

That doesnt do the trick for me though because i think it has to be a conditional count applied to the rolling 52 week windows.  In other words, count only true values over the last 52 weeks.
Struggling with trying to figure out the correct api or methods to use for this to do it in a most efficient manner...any help would be appreciated.

---

**UPDATE: This might be a possible solution im thinking:**

```
df1['52wkh'] = df1['high'].rolling(min_periods=1, window=252).max()
#mark all 52 week high that meets this condition
df1['is_52wkch'] = df1['close'] >= df1.shift(1)['52wkh']
#count the occurrences of above over the last 52 weeks
df1['is_52wkch_cnt'] = df1.rolling(window=252)['is_52wkch'].sum()
```

So i think after this, i would be able to filter on is_52wkch==True and is_52wkch_cnt == 1 to get the first 52 week high marked within last 52 weeks

Does this look correct?

Comment: are you wanting it to be the high for the previous 52 weeks, or for the 52 weeks centred on the current value (i.e., 182 days before, 182 days after)?

Comment: 2021-12-27 close(4791.189941) is more than the past 52wkh (2021-11-22) for 2021-11-22, this is understandable. But, how is the situation for 2023-06-12 4338.930176 no more than 4818.620117? In any case, I sketched a few options below.

Comment: @mark basically with in a lookback of 52 weeks at any point in time, there should be only 1 52 week  high marked as true.

Comment: @inquirer re: 2023-06-12, it is greater and so marked as true

Comment: @mike01010 then I don't understand you. Write step by step how you want to get the values (reduce the window to small values for more clarity).

Comment: i think i have a solution. it was close to what i had above. will post it for review

Comment: It's clear. Didn't really explain. And now there is a solution ... Why did you ask then? I had no plans to participate in your extras.

Comment: @inquirer. Sorry. If im asking, it's because im stuck and looking for ideas or to problem solve with others. it doesn't mean i have given up or im just looking for others to write my code for me.  So i continue trying...occasionally, that means i may find a solution, other times with help of others, and still other time - someone provides a workable solution.  but im not the type to just sit and wait. i apologize if you feel offended by this.

Comment: @mike01010, the thing is, if the data is ascending (i.e. say the data goes 1 2 3 4 5), then there will be more than one n week/day high. I think what you want is the second option, though you may not understand

Comment: @mike01010 If you want the first maximum since the beginning of the history, then look at the first option df.loc[imax[0], 'high'], if the last one then df.loc[imax[-1], 'high'] imax is a list of all row indices where the maxima were recorded. Or, by slice through loc, take the data from the beginning or from the end, as you need. And find the maximum.

Comment: @Mark that was precisely the problem. getting 52 week highs is not a problem. getting the first one within a sliding window is what i was trying to solve for - with the caveat that as the window slides, there can be N number of 52 week highs within that window. What i have above, basically 2 rolling counts seems to allow for me to filter for that first occurrence.  (Though im not sure if it's the most efficient or best way to solve for this - but so far seems to work)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I totally follow what you're looking to do (your example uses a 52 week rolling average, but your data doesn't go over 52 weeks).

But, with that said, the following should produce a column with a n day rolling average, and then you can just get the days where the high is equal to the rolling average high (caveat: this is assuming you have a row for every day in your dataframe. If this isn't the case, then you would simply be getting a rolling average high of the previous n records, though these may not necessarily be the last n days)1

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['2021-11-22', '2021-12-27', '2021-12-28', '2021-12-30', '2022-01-04', '2023-06-12', '2023-06-13', '2023-06-14', '2023-06-15', '2023-06-16'],
    'close': [4682.939941, 4791.189941, 4786.350098, 4778.729980, 4793.540039, 4338.930176, 4369.009766, 4372.589844, 4425.839844, 4409.589844],
    'high': [4743.830078, 4791.490234, 4807.020020, 4808.930176, 4818.620117, 4340.129883, 4375.370117, 4391.819824, 4439.200195, 4448.470215],
})


def n_day_high(n, df):
    df[f'{n}_day_high'] = df['high'].rolling(n).max()

n_day_high(3, df)

df['is_high'] = df['high'] == df['3_day_high']

         date        close         high   3_day_high  is_high
0  2021-11-22  4682.939941  4743.830078          NaN    False
1  2021-12-27  4791.189941  4791.490234          NaN    False
2  2021-12-28  4786.350098  4807.020020  4807.020020     True
3  2021-12-30  4778.729980  4808.930176  4808.930176     True
4  2022-01-04  4793.540039  4818.620117  4818.620117     True
5  2023-06-12  4338.930176  4340.129883  4818.620117    False
6  2023-06-13  4369.009766  4375.370117  4818.620117    False
7  2023-06-14  4372.589844  4391.819824  4391.819824     True
8  2023-06-15  4425.839844  4439.200195  4439.200195     True
9  2023-06-16  4409.589844  4448.470215  4448.470215     True
```

Comment: this i understand and i think i have..but what im looking for is the first occurrence to be flagged only. so in above where you are using n=3, 2021-12-28,  2022-01-04 and 2023-06-14 would be the only rows marked as true.  the catch here is 2022-01-04...while there were other 52 week highs within the n-day period, there wasn't any based on the condition im looking for, so it would be marked as True.  why i think the whole thing has to be maybe a second rolling condition

Comment: in that case, the only thing you need to change is `rolling(n)` to be `rolling(n, Center=True)`

Comment: but even then, there will be examples of multiple `True`s in a row (it will always be the case when the newest value is an n day high)

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)  # print everything rows
pd.options.display.expand_frame_repr = False

df = yf.download('AAPL', start='2017-01-01', end='2023-06-03')

df = df.reset_index()
imax = df['High'].rolling(window=5, center=False).apply(lambda x: x.idxmax()).values

count0_imax = np.count_nonzero(np.isnan(imax))
imax = imax[count0_imax:].astype(int)
imax = np.unique(imax)


df.loc[imax, 'first_max'] = ['this_first_max ' + str(i) for i in range(len(imax))]
```

and if you need the maximum in this row:

```
df.loc[imax, 'max'] = df.loc[imax, 'High']
```

If you just need a line where the maximum is in the window then:
Since [idxmax](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) needs integer indices, I reset them. Reduced the window to 5 to make it easier to see everything
Since indexes can be duplicated for each window, I take only unique ones.

And I generate the string 'this_first_max ' + str(i) to set via loc to the column 'ferst_max'. But, keep in mind that for several windows there can be one and the same line with a maximum (this_first_max).

Actually I think you are looking for something like Donchian Channel signals.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df['52wkh'] = df['High'].rolling(min_periods=1, window=252).max()
mask_one = (df['52wkh'].shift(1)!= df['52wkh'])

ind = df[mask_one].index

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df.index, df['High'])
ax.plot(df.index, df['52wkh'])
ax.plot(ind, df.loc[ind, '52wkh'], 'o', color='red', markersize=5, linewidth=4)

fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

Here in mask_one masks are obtained where '52wkh' changes with respect to the previous value and then the indexes of these lines are obtained.

And what you are probably looking for is a previous high closing price crossover. '^' is the current close and 'o' is the previous one.

```
mask_two = (df['Close'] >= df['52wkh'].shift(1)) & (df['Close'].shift(1) < df['52wkh'].shift(2))

ind = df[mask_two].index


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df.index, df['Close'], label ='Close')
ax.plot(df.index, df['52wkh'].shift(1), label ='52wkh.shift(1)')
ax.plot(ind, df.loc[ind, 'Close'], '^', color='red', markersize=5, linewidth=4)
ax.plot(ind-1, df.loc[ind-1, 'Close'], 'o', color='red', markersize=5, linewidth=4)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

Comment: thanks, i will have a look at these solutions. i can say the 2nd (Donchian Channel) and 3rd solution is what i had previously, but isn't what i want. if there are 3+ consecutive  52 week daily highs, that would mark more than 1 of those as true i think, when it should mark only the first.  The idmax is interesting and i have been playing with that, but havent gotten it quite right yet. will try yours

Comment: if it is difficult to explain, you can draw and show here, it will be much easier to understand what you need. You say you need to update a maximum of three times in a row, so what (figuratively speaking, there should be three vertices, each higher than the previous one), right?